# Fill the primefaces datatable with data

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

i am using the primefaces(I use PF 3.5) [datatable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf) and I want to fill the table with data from my db.

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{productservice.getListOrderedByDate()}"
    editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="productTable">
```

my service method looks like that:

```
public List<Product> getListOrderedByDate() {
    log.trace("Returning list of Products...");
    log.info(productDAO.getProductsOrderedByDate());
    return productDAO.getProductsOrderedByDate();
}
```

However, when I render the table in my `xhtml` page I get `No records found.` back.

I really appreciate your answer!!!

**UPDATE**

```
   <p:dataTable var="product" value="#{productservice.getListOrderedByDate}"> 

                            <f:facet name="header"> Product  </f:facet>

                            <p:column headerText="id" style="width:15%">
                                <h:outputText value="#{product.id}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Object Type" style="width:15%">
                                <h:outputText value="#{product.objectType}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Price" style="width:15%">
                                <h:outputText value="#" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="For" style="width:15%">
                                <h:outputText value="#{product.for}" />
                            </p:column>
```

**UPDATE 2**

my method product ordered by date:

```
public List<Product> getProductsOrderedByDate() {
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Product> criteria = cb.createQuery(Product.class);
  Root<Product> product = criteria.from(Product.class);

  criteria.select(product).orderBy(cb.desc(product.get("creationDate")));
  return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: You need to provide more UI code(xhtml,...)

Comment: I updated my quesiton again(only with a simple data grid)

Comment: Are you sure your List(productDAO.getProductsOrderedByDate()) have data ?

Comment: yep I am sure, because my db is filled with data and I wrote a test program that gives me the data back...

Comment: If you sure about "return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();" return data, i can not imagine your issue. I have just tested simple example like you, and it work fine for me. Please try to debug you service !

Comment: I think I did sth wrong in my `xhtml` file, because the data does not get loaded...

Comment: So you can try simple datatable: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf

Comment: When I declare the `value = #{productservice.getListOrderedByDate}`, do I have to look at upper and lower case letters?

Comment: Yes, you must, or you can try @Junavis notice.

Comment: because now I get: `Unable to find method [getListOrderedByDate] with [0] parameters`

Comment: oh, you need to use: value="#{productservice.getListOrderedByDate()}", you miss () characters.

Comment: thx it works!!!! please write it as an answer and I will accept it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @Juvanis solution, or in your chosen you need to use:

```
 <p:dataTable var="product" value="#{productservice.getListOrderedByDate()}">
```

Instead of:

```
 <p:dataTable var="product" value="#{productservice.getListOrderedByDate}">
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that you set value in a wrong way.

```
value="#{yourBean.listOfCars}"
```

value is expected to be a iterable type of list.

See the showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf;jsessionid=1c0z4mgiaz5531cqf4v78m79iy

Comment: thx a lot for your answer! However, I do not get it ;( I am already returning a list from my DAO why is my notation false?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the value attribute is correct?

In my opinion it should be

```
 value="#{productservice.listOrderedByDate}
```

and not

```
value="#{productservice.getListOrderedByDate}"
```